# Is my iPhone model number MC922LL/A unlocked or locked?

Tags: iphone, unlock, apple-store

I have seen that there are many other model numbers of iPhone 4S's, but I have not seen any info about model number MC922ll/A

Is an iPhone 4S of this model unlocked or locked to a specific mobile carrier?

Answer (score 1):

I got a 4S MC922LL as replacement phone from A pple(my 4S was having issues).

I put my friend's T-Mobile sim and it is working.
I've tried it multiple times even after restarting the phone and it is still working with the T-Mobile Sim.

It seems to be unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like it is here in the UK, it's the device's UID that determines whether it is locked - Apple have a massive database of the UID's along with references as to whether they are locked (this is why warrantee swap-outs always come out with the same lock).

Normally contacting the networks, if you're a customer in 'good standing' they'll let you unlock for 'international use' - which is exactly the same as unlocking the phone.

Answer (score 1):

AT&T has a site to check and ask for device unlock:

- https://www.att.com/es-us/deviceunlock/#/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please use translation to get your post into english - a comment if you are not a native speaker also helps people know that you require translation assistance as opposed to being lazy with the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from various sales websites that this model number is locked to AT&T. [(Source)](http://www.translatorselectronics.com/lackfriday/apple-iphone-4s-16gb-locked-to-att-black-B005VGK5EO)

Answer (score 0):

I have this iphone model # and it's actually one of the first iphone 4s that were sold by AT&T via their site/retail/warehouse. It can be unlocked via Appple or At&T themselves. I got it unlocked when my contract expired and moved to T-mobile ever since.